# как передать параметр(переменную-массив) из функции в функцию

Tags: php, yii2, парсер

Подскажите как передать параметр $site_url из public function actionNews в public function actionsOneNews для дальнейшего парсинга контента.
Парсю список новостей, записываю их в БД, потом нужно вытянуть адрес каждой новости и передать его для дальнейшего парсинга контента. 
Конторллер:

```
    public function actionNews()
{
    $arr = ParseAllNews::newsList();
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
            $model = new ParseAllNews();
            $model->img = $arr[$key]["img"];
            $model->text = $arr[$key]["text"];
            $model->title = $arr[$key]["title"];
            $model->url = $arr[$key]["site_url"];
            $model->save();
            }
}

public function actionsOneNews($site_url)
{
    $news = Content::OneNews($site_url);
    foreach ($news as $key => $value){
        $model = new  Content();
        $model->img = $news[$key]["img"];
        $model->text = $news[$key]["text"];
        $model->title = $news[$key]["title"];
        $model->save();
    }
}
```

Модель ParseAllNews:

```
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'news';
}

public static function newsList(){
    $site = "http://site.ru/";

    $client = new Client();

    $res = $client->request('GET', 'http://site.ru');

    $body = $res->getBody();

    $document = \phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($body);

    $links = $document->find('.bordered-title');

    foreach ($links as $link) {
        $link = pq($link);
        $a = $link->find('a', 0)->attr('href');
        $site_url = $site . $a;
        $get = $client->request('GET', $site_url);
        $body_get = $get->getBody();
        $document = \phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($body_get);
        $links_get = $document->find('.b-longgrid-column .item.article');
        $links_get->find('.item__info')->remove();
        foreach ($links_get as $link_get){
            $img = pq($link_get)->find('img')->attr('src');
            $text = pq($link_get)->find('.rightcol')->html();
            $title = pq($link_get)->find('.titles a>span')->html();
            $url = pq($link_get)->find('.titles h3 a')->attr('href');
            $site_url = $site . $url;
            $i++;
            $mas[$i] = array('title' => $title, 'img' => $img, 'text' => $text, 'site_url' => $site_url, );
        }
    }
    return $mas;
}
```

Модель Content:

```
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'content';
}

public function getNews()
{
    return $this->hasOne(News::className(), ['id' => 'news_id']);
}

public static function OneNews($site_url){

    // создаем экземпляр класса
    $client = new Client();
    // отправляем запрос к странице Яндекса
    $res = $client->request('GET', $site_url);
    // получаем данные между открывающим и закрывающим тегами body
    $body = $res->getBody();
    // подключаем phpQuery
    $document = \phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($body);
    // получаем список новостей
    $news = $document->find('.b-topic');
    // выполняем проход циклом по списку
    foreach ($news as $article) {
        //pq аналог $ в jQuery
        $article = pq($article);
        $img = $article->find('img')->attr('src');
        $text = $article->find('.b-text')->html();
        $title = $article->find('.b-topic__title')->html();
        $rightcol = $article->find('.b-topic__rightcol')->html();
        $i++;
        $mas[$i] = array('title' => $title, 'img' => $img, 'text' => $text, 'rightcol' => $rightcol);

    }
    return $mas;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class SiteController extends Controller{

  /*
  * В классе контроллера определяешь свойство:
  */
  private $_siteUrl; // сюда будет записан url

  public function actionNews(){

    //....

    /*
    * Записываешь нужное значение в свойство.
    */
    $this->_siteUrl = $model->url; // или откуда берется адрес

    //....
  }

  public function actionsOneNews(){

    // ....
    /*
    * Используешь полученное значение как душе угодно.
    */
    if($this->_siteUrl) returt "Hello News!";

    // ....
  }
}
```

т.е определил свойство в классе, в одном методе задал ему значение, в другом прочитал это значение.

Comment: Решение хорошее но параметр у меня массив ссылок и когда пишу как вы говорите выдает ошибку. что параметр должен быть строкой или объектом. 'The parameter class is expected to be either a string or an object'

Comment: Не знаю нужно тогда или запускать как то один за одним две функции что бы передавал параметр по одному значению и парсинг контента происходил сразу за парсингом статьи или как то по другому его отдать.

Comment: Если парсер принимает ссылку в виде строки, то можно: а. взять массив ссылок и запустить парсер в цикле, собирая новую переменную с результатами парсинга, и б. уточнить индекс в массиве: $this->_siteUrl[0].

Answer (score 0):

Делай return $site_url из public function actionNews
затем

```
$a = new actionNews();
actionsOneNews($a);
```

Comment: Что те не совсем понял где создавать экземпляр класса там же в контроллере что ли? и  actionNews это функция, а не класс или вы имели в виду под ним newControllerName где он лежит?